# Shell script file (.sh) does not run, and throws an error

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to linux, and I have a shell script (.sh) file on my Desktop that I want to run.
These are the steps that I did:

This is the content of the `test.sh` file on my Desktop:

```
    #!bin/bash
    #test.sh
    echo "test"
```

I want to run (Execute) `test.sh` through the terminal. These are the commands that I'm using:

```
cd Desktop
```

I give permission to run `test.sh` with:

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

and then try to open the file:

```
test.sh
```

But I get this error:

```
test.sh: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your current directory is *NOT* in the default Linux path.  For good reasons.  Try this instead: `./test.sh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> bash: ./test.sh: bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Replace:

```
#!bin/bash
```

With:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548073/shell-script-file-sh-does-not-run-and-throws-an-error/548077#548077)

Comment: This answers a follow-up question, but not the actual question asked.

Answer (score 4):

Your shell will search the directories in your `$PATH` environment variable for executable files.

If the current directory is not in it (and your Desktop directory won't be, by default), you must specify the path explicitly.

```
./test.sh
```

Comment: I test this that you said **./test.sh** but now terminal says **bash: ./test.sh: bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory**

Comment: @ahmadabedini — Because you don't have a copy of `bash` in `~/Desktop/bin/bash`. You need to put the correct path to `bash` in the shebang line (you forgot the `/`).

Comment: Can you please give me an Example. I can't understand. or pleas give me a link about the thing that you say.  How to put correct path and what is ~/Desktop/bin/bash?

Comment: what is **~/Desktop/bin/bash** And what does he should do ?

Comment: Sorry Again: Terminal says: **bash: ./test.sh: ~/Desktop/bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory**

Comment: @ahmadabedini — I said "you forgot the `/`", put it at the front of the path to bash. `~/Desktop/bin/bash` is where you were already looking, but it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Kermani — `~/Desktop/bin/bash` is what you get when you take `~/Desktop/` and look for `bin/bash`. It throws an error because it doesn't eist.

Comment: This is true answer. AND THANK YOU TOO. http://askubuntu.com/questions/548073/shell-script-file-sh-does-not-run-and-throws-an-error/548077#548077

Answer (score 0):

try running the script like this: `./test.sh`

Answer (score -2):

Do like this:

FIRST WAY:
bash test.sh

or

sh test.sh